# O python não possui biblioteca mysql.connector no Xubuntu

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, linux

Já tentei várias coisas para instalar essa bendita biblioteca, meu projeto é para terça que vem(02/11/2002) e infelizmente não consegui instalar no Xubuntu...

```
sudo pip3 mysql.connector
```

Preciso dessa biblioteca , senão meu código inteiro trava.
Obrigado, abraços.

Comment: Por favor, coloque na sua pergunta o erro que está sendo gerado para podermos ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bartô,

Acabo de fazer a instalação sem problemas no Linux, acho que você se confundiu, veja:

Ao fazer o import dessa biblioteca em um fonte python, você faz da seguinte forma:

```
import mysql.connector
```

Porém ao fazer a instalação pelo pip, essa biblioteca tem outro nome, trata-se da mysql-connector-python, tente instalar da seguinte forma:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

***Obs.***: Não precisei utilizar de sudo

---

> Referência:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python

Comment: Olha, muito obrigado viu? Funcionou!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Vlw mesmo :)